# Azure blob storage equivalent to S3 website redirect

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

S3 has its own defined metadata for redirects: `x-amz-website-redirect-location` ([WebsiteRedirectLocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#PutObjectInput.SetWebsiteRedirectLocation)).
But I don't see anything equivalent for [Azure blob storage](https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/storage#Blob). Is there any first class support for this or should I should use a custom key in blob metadata?

(I've referenced golang apis, but that's just to show one API implementation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't see anything equivalent for Azure blob storage. Is there any first class support for this or should I should use a custom key in blob metadata?

If you want to set redirect requests for an object to another object in the same bucket or to an external URL in the Azure storage, based on my knowledge, **it is not supported** on the Azure blob storage. If you want to know more about Azure storage blob metadata, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata).

If you want to find the similar feature as [Configuring a Webpage Redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html), you could host the web page on the [Azure WebApp service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) and could set your [redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/) rule.

**Reference:**

[Azure Tip — just a Web App with redirect please](https://michelebusta.com/azure-tip-just-a-web-app-with-redirect-please-a045d1072659)